# Select All Rows after applying filter to Magento2 Extended Grid

Tags: magento2, grid, multiselect

I am working on Magento 2.2.0. I have an extended grid in my custom module. When I apply the filter to the grid and choose "Select All" from the drop-down, it is not working. All the row ids are posting to the controller.

I want it to post only the rows which are visible after applying the filter. Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: What ids are you getting in your collectionfactory?

Comment: No i am not working with massaction. I have posted data to controller save action